# Background color of Chakra UI Solid Button disappear

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, tailwind-css, chakra-ui

I used button component from Chakra UI in my Next JS project. I used the button variant solid but its background color would disappear and only showed after I hovered it. I tried other variants and they worked well.

This is how I use the components.

```
"use client";

import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { ArrowForwardIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";

export function Nav({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex">
        <Button colorScheme="green" variant="outline">Masuk</Button>
        <Button colorScheme="green" variant="solid" rightIcon={<ArrowForwardIcon />}>
          Daftar
        </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I already set up the provider in my `layout.js` file. I also tried to define the backgroundColor manually via props but it also disappeared. I thought it was caused by my tailwind setting but I use the default setting from the Next.js installation and just changed the HTML background color in `globals.css` to white.

This is my `layout.js`.

```
import "@styles/globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { Providers } from "@components/Providers";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

And I put the provider here.

```
"use client";

import { CacheProvider } from "@chakra-ui/next-js";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export function Providers({ children }) {
  return (
    <CacheProvider>
      <ChakraProvider>{children}</ChakraProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}
```

[image]

I use chakra-ui/next-js ver. 2.1.4 and next ver. 13.4.4

What should I do? I'm confused because I'm new to Next. js and Chakra UI. Thank you

Comment: I have tested the exact code you provided and it just work perfectly. Which version of chakra are you using ?

Comment: It seems you are using app route. Please kindly provide your layout.ts and theme.ts.

Comment: I use chakra 2.1.4 version. @Faouzi21

Comment: I already added my layout.js and provider.js. May I know what file theme.ts is used for? Because I don't have it. @TomFan

Comment: theme.ts is nearly equal to tailwind.config.js, https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/theme, https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started. Also, I dont think you need tailwind and chakra ui together. The bundle size is large. Just choose one.

Comment: I just uninstalled tailwind and the components from chakra-ui work fine! Thank you so much for helping me @TomFan

Answer (score 9):

That's because Tailwind resets the CSS with their [preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight). You can find the whole reset file [here](https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@3.3.3/src/css/preflight.css), and here's the code block that makes your Chakra UI button disappear:

```
/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Remove default button styles.
*/

button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
}
```

You can just use Tailwind classes to color your button, but if you want to use Charka UI's `colorScheme` property, you'd have to disable the preflight values in `tailwind.config.js`

```
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  // ...other config
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
}
```

But keep in mind that if you do this you are disabling ALL of their reset CSS properties, which is only good if you have another styling system (e.g. Chakra UI).

I also agree with a comment on your post that you probably don't need both TailwindCSS and Chakra UI, because they are too big together.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall tailwind on my project and the chakra UI works. It seems the packaged overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it by uninstalling the chakra ui and try with tailwind css because using both of the frameworks may result you to this